# Postgres SQL query - averages per month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries which I want to achieve.

I have a table like so...

```
Date        | Period | Location | Price
2017-01-01      1         A         10
2017-01-01      2         A         15
2017-01-01      1         B         15
2017-01-01      2         B         16
```

Each date has 48 readings (one every half hour).

Query 1:  I wish to get the average prices for any given location within a date range in the following format:

e.g. Between 2017-01-01 and 2017-06-30, average price per period for location 'A'

```
  Period 1  | Period 2|  Period 3 ...
       10           11          15
```

Query 2:  I wish to have the average price for any given location going back x number of months: (period does not matter)

```
Month   |  Average price
january        10
february       12
march          16
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You have two distinct questions here. I would suggest you ask them separately.

Comment: Did you try anything ?.. looks fairly simple `select` queries is all needed

Comment: I have this one for the first query.  Actually I am more concerned with the second query anyway... SELECT period, avg(price)/10 as price FROM table where location='A' group by period order by period;

Comment: For the first query, you want the period data pivoted?

Answer (score 1):

The second query you listed is a very simple `group by` operation. The only thing that's slightly tricky about it is that you need to extract the month from the listed date.

```
select
    date_part('month', t.Date) as month,
    avg(t.Price) as average_price
from
    mytable t
group by
    date_part('month', t.Date)
```

---

The first query however is significantly more complicated. It involves the `crosstab()`, which you'll have to enable in your database if you haven't already. The general idea is to calculate the averages for each period, and then pivot the data much like you would in excel.

```
select * from crosstab(
'   select
        t.Period
        , avg(t.Price) as avg_price
    from
        mytable t
    group by
        t.Period
    order by
        1
        , 2
'
) as ct(
    "Period" text
    , "1"  int
    , "2"  int
    , "3"  int
    , "4"  int
    , "5"  int
    , "6"  int
    , "7"  int
    , "8"  int
    , "9"  int
    , "10" int
    , "11" int
    , "12" int
)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/1142368) has a great amount of information on Postgre's `crosstab()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I get the following error though...
ERROR:  invalid source data SQL statement
DETAIL:  The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid source data SQL statement
SQL state: 22023
Detail: The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.

Comment: It won't be good if you have rows from different years because `date_part('month', t.Date)` will return the same.


For example `date_part('month', '2017-01-01')` returns the same value as `date_part('month', '2018-01-01')`.


`DATE_TRUNC('month', t.Date)` will be better in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

First question:

You need a pivot. If you do not want to do this in a static way (name all period columns manually in the query) you could to it with a more dynamic way with JSON:

[SQL Fiddle Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/408e81/4)

Result:

```
{"Period 1": 15.0000000000000000, "Period 2": 22.5000000000000000, "Period 3": 100.0000000000000000, "Period 4": 150.0000000000000000}
```

You get a JSON string which can be used for further calculations, e.g.

```
SELECT json_pivot -> 'Period 2' FROM (/* subquery */)
```

see here: [SQL Fiddle: Further calculation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/408e81/6)

With the JSON functions you can get a dynamic pseudo pivot result.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_object_agg(period, avg) as pivot_json         -- B
FROM (
    SELECT 
        'Period ' || period as period,  AVG(price)      -- A
    FROM 
        period_prices pp
    WHERE 
        location = 'A' 
        AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30'
    GROUP BY location, period
)s
```

A: Grouping by location and period, renaming the period number to "Period [number]"

B: `jsonb_object_agg` aggregates two columns to the shown result.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

---

Second question is a simple `GROUP BY`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/408e81/11)

```
SELECT
    to_char(pp.date, 'month') as month,    
    avg(pp.price) as avg_price
FROM
    period_prices pp
GROUP BY
    to_char(pp.date, 'month')
```

You could group by `date_part`. But while `date_part('month', ...)` gives you the number of the month (which is the preferred solution for further calculations) you wanted to get the month's name in the end. For that you can use the `to_char()` function.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html